# AngularJS value being passed as undefined

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to pass a value into a function in AngularJS:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="d in departments">
    <div>
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="userType">Department</label>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select id="department" class="form-control" ng-model="d.departmentKey" ng-init="listDepartments()" ng-options="dl.deptkey as dl.deptName for dl in getDepartmentList" ng-change="listSubDepartments(d)"></select>
        </div>
    </div>               
 </div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module("timesheetManagement").controller("addNewUserCtrl", function ($scope, addUserResource) {
    $scope.listSubDepartments = function (d) {
        var departmentKey = d.departmentKey
    }
}
```

But for some reason d.departmentKey just gets passed as "undefined"

Comment: For the dropdown box?

Comment: Plunker link? please

Comment: the departments array.

Comment: I think you have to put ng-init="listDepartments() in a upper level.

Answer (score 0):

Try without passing variable as follows

```
$scope.listSubDepartments = function () {
    var departmentKey = $scope.d.departmentKey
}
```

Because you have already defined a ng-model which is available on $scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is undefined 'cause you don't pass it actually. You should use `ng-init="listDepartments(d)"` to provide value to the function.

And probably `ng-init` is not a perfect way to do this, since it executes only once